# Under what conditions can we move the limit symbol through the logarithm symbol?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was reading the derivation of the derivation of a log function. And saw this: 
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\log_b x]= \frac{1}{x}\lim_{v \to 0} [\log_b(1+v)^\frac{1}{v}]$$

Then, the limit notation gets moved through the logarithm symbol. But the book's side note says that

> $\log_b x$ is continuous on (0, $+\infty$) [x is pre-defined to be limited to (0,$+\infty$)], so we can move the limit through the function symbol.

$$\frac{1}{x} \log_b [\lim_{v \to 0} (1+v)^\frac{1}{v}]$$

**but why is that? How does continuity have to do with whether we can move through the limit symbol?**

Comment: What is the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit and continuity respectively?

Comment: @Rubertos, barely know anything about that definition. My teacher uses the intuitive approach. I am in introductory course.

Comment: If you cannot define limit and continuity formally, you cannot prove it..

Comment: @Rubertos, hey maybe you can just write an answer down anyway if I won't really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ being continuous is equivalent to the property that if $x_n \to x$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Comment: I guess you meant $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$...

Comment: @Pavel, yes thank you

Comment: Not really I guess. I mean even if a point is missing, the general trend is still there.

Comment: But does this answers question? I have a hard one seeing...

Comment: Yes, it means you can always pass a limit through a continuous functions, as by definition the limit of the evaluations will be equal to evaluation at the limit. Assuming of course a limit exists.